# Check if input is focused (spacebar is in use)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just ran into this issue. I'm using a spacebar to play/pause one main player on the page. While doing some tests I discovered that if I'm typing in a search or comments and press spacebar than it just keeps playing and pausing the player which gets annoying. I was looking up ways to check if input is focused than don't use spacebar for play / pause else use it for play pause, but couldn't find a solution.

In terms of logic I would need to do something like

```
if (unicode == 32  "SPACEBAR" && "No input is focused, so spacebar is not used for typing ") {

//Some stuff here

 }
```

Comment: Where is the key press listener attached? Try attaching it to the play/pause input.

Comment: @Pietu1998 its a $(document).keydown so no meter where on a page user is, they can play pause it with spacebar at any time. This should stay like it is, however I need to check if user is currently trying to comment or search for something, than give spacebar its normal functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `document.activeElement` for this and check type.

For example:

```
document.activeElement.nodeName === 'INPUT'
```

So your if should be like:

```
if( unicode == '32' && document.activeElement.nodeName !== 'INPUT' ) {
    // play/pause video
}
```

Comment: coerce type useless here so better to use ===

Comment: So would I use it like `var userIsTyping = document.activeElement.nodeName === 'INPUT'` and then in if statement `unicode == 32 && !userIsTyping` sorry for re-asking, still new to this

Comment: @Ilya please provide actual IF condition and I will modify it.

Comment: It's simply checking if it's a spacebar so `if (unicode == 32) {}` and than I handle play pause inside such if statement

Answer (score 0):

Check document.activeElement

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.activeElement#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Use **event target** property:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
       if(!$(e.target).is('input[type=text]') && unicode === 32) {
           //stuff here
       }
    });
```